# Python: How can i reverse first 2 characters of a string?

Tags: python, string, reverse

Please help, I am new and I am trying to solve some online questions. I am stuck in a place.

How to print the first two letter of a string in reverse? For eg-

```
word = "abc"
print(word[1:0:-1])
```

would return `'b'` and not `'ba'`

Comment: The first two values in a slice are "start" and "stop", but the stop actually isn't included. So it's only getting the index 1. To go all the way to the beginning or end, you can use `None` or just leave it blank. So `word[1::-1]` means "start and index one, go till the start or end, going back by -1 indices each time.

Comment: Haskell has a cute solution here: `rev (a:b:_) = [b, a]; rev xs = xs`

Answer (score 3):

The end is not included when splitting, so do this:

```
>>> word = 'abc'
>>> word[1::-1]
'ba'
```

Leaving the middle empty will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 0

```
print(word[1::-1])
```

The middle index specifies where to stop the slice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this,

```
word = "hello"
newword = ""
for i in range(len(word)):
    newword += word[-i-1]

print(newword) //olleh
```

This reverses the entire word. Then you can take the first two of `newword`. 
Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

To print ***reverse last k characters***,

```
>>>word="baseball"
>>>n=4
print(word[:-n-1:-1])//llab
```

This is simple step to reverse last k characters without using any loops

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(s):
   if len(s)>=2:
      return s[1]+s[0]+s[2:]
```